# Property "handle" does not exist on type "undefined" - react context and typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context, react-hook-form

I'm converting my app from JS to TS. Everything has been working good under JS but when started conversion to TS I'm getting plenty of errors with handle functions like for example handleVideoAdd. Does anyone has idea what am I'm doing wrong? Tried many things without success...

*Property 'handleVideoAdd' does not exist on type 'undefined'.  TS2339* - and it's pointing out to this fragment of code:

`const { handleVideoAdd, inputURL, handleInputURLChange } =  useContext(Context)`

My code looks like that:

- Header.tsx

```
    import { Context } from "../Context";
    import React, { useContext } from "react";
    import { Navbar, Button, Form, FormControl } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function Header() {
  const { handleVideoAdd, inputURL, handleInputURLChange } =
    useContext(Context);
  return (
    <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
      <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Video App</Navbar.Brand>
      <Form onSubmit={handleVideoAdd} inline>
        <FormControl
          type="text"
          name="url"
          placeholder="Paste url"
          value={inputURL}
          onChange={handleInputURLChange}
          className="mr-sm-2"
        />
        <Button type="submit" variant="outline-success">
          Add
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
```

- Context.tsx

```
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { youtubeApi } from "./APIs/youtubeAPI";
import { vimeoApi } from "./APIs/vimeoAPI";
import React from "react";
import type { FormEvent } from "react";

const Context = React.createContext(undefined);

function ContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [inputURL, setInputURL] = useState("");
  const [videoData, setVideoData] = useState(() => {
    const videoData = localStorage.getItem("videoData");
    if (videoData) {
      return JSON.parse(videoData);
    }
    return [];
  });
  const [filterType, setFilterType] = useState("");
  const [videoSources, setVideoSources] = useState([""]);
  const [wasSortedBy, setWasSortedBy] = useState(false);
  const [showVideoModal, setShowVideoModal] = useState(false);
  const [modalData, setModalData] = useState({});
  const [showWrongUrlModal, setShowWrongUrlModal] = useState(false);

  const createModalSrc = (videoItem) => {
    if (checkVideoSource(videoItem.id) === "youtube") {
      setModalData({
        src: `http://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoItem.id}`,
        name: videoItem.name,
      });
    } else {
      setModalData({
        src: `https://player.vimeo.com/video/${videoItem.id}`,
        name: videoItem.name,
      });
    }
  };

  const handleVideoModalShow = (videoID) => {
    createModalSrc(videoID);
    setShowVideoModal(true);
  };
  const handleVideoModalClose = () => setShowVideoModal(false);

  const handleWrongUrlModalShow = () => setShowWrongUrlModal(true);

  const handleWrongUrlModalClose = () => setShowWrongUrlModal(false);

  const handleInputURLChange = (e) => {
    setInputURL(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const handleVideoAdd = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const source = checkVideoSource(inputURL);

    if (source === "youtube") {
      handleYouTubeVideo(inputURL);
    } else if (source === "vimeo") {
      handleVimeoVideo(inputURL);
    } else {
      handleWrongUrlModalShow();
    }
  };

  const checkVideoSource = (inputURL) => {
    if (inputURL.includes("youtu") || inputURL.length === 11) {
      return "youtube";
    } else if (inputURL.includes("vimeo") || inputURL.length === 9) {
      return "vimeo";
    }
  };

  const checkURL = (inputURL) => {
    if (!inputURL.includes("http")) {
      const properURL = `https://${inputURL}`;
      return properURL;
    } else {
      return inputURL;
    }
  };

  const checkInputType = (inputURL) => {
    if (!inputURL.includes("http") && inputURL.length === 11) {
      return "id";
    } else if (!inputURL.includes("http") && inputURL.length === 9) {
      return "id";
    } else {
      return "url";
    }
  };

  const fetchYouTubeData = async (videoID) => {
    const data = await youtubeApi(videoID);
    if (data.items.length === 0) {
      handleWrongUrlModalShow();
    } else {
      setVideoData((state) => [
        ...state,
        {
          id: videoID,
          key: `${videoID}${Math.random()}`,
          name: data.items[0].snippet.title,
          thumbnail: data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.medium.url, //default, medium, high
          viewCount: data.items[0].statistics.viewCount,
          likeCount: data.items[0].statistics.likeCount,
          savedDate: new Date(),
          favourite: false,
          source: "YouTube",
          url: inputURL,
        },
      ]);
      setInputURL("");
    }
  };

  const handleYouTubeVideo = (inputURL) => {
    const inputType = checkInputType(inputURL);

    if (inputType === "id") {
      fetchYouTubeData(inputURL);
    } else {
      const checkedURL = checkURL(inputURL);
      const url = new URL(checkedURL);
      if (inputURL.includes("youtube.com")) {
        const params = url.searchParams;
        const videoID = params.get("v");
        fetchYouTubeData(videoID);
      } else {
        const videoID = url.pathname.split("/");
        fetchYouTubeData(videoID[1]);
      }
    }
  };

  const fetchVimeoData = async (videoID) => {
    const data = await vimeoApi(videoID);

    if (data.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
      handleWrongUrlModalShow();
    } else {
      setVideoData((state) => [
        ...state,
        {
          id: videoID,
          key: `${videoID}${Math.random()}`,
          name: data.name,
          thumbnail: data.pictures.sizes[2].link, //0-8
          savedDate: new Date(),
          viewCount: data.stats.plays,
          likeCount: data.metadata.connections.likes.total,
          savedDate: new Date(),
          favourite: false,
          source: "Vimeo",
          url: inputURL,
        },
      ]);
      setInputURL("");
    }
  };

  const handleVimeoVideo = (inputURL) => {
    const inputType = checkInputType(inputURL);

    if (inputType === "id") {
      fetchVimeoData(inputURL);
    } else {
      const checkedURL = checkURL(inputURL);
      const url = new URL(checkedURL);
      const videoID = url.pathname.split("/");
      fetchVimeoData(videoID[1]);
    }
  };

  const deleteVideo = (key) => {
    let newArray = [...videoData].filter((video) => video.key !== key);
    setWasSortedBy(true);
    setVideoData(newArray);
  };

  const deleteAllData = () => {
    setVideoData([]);
  };

  const toggleFavourite = (key) => {
    let newArray = [...videoData];
    newArray.map((item) => {
      if (item.key === key) {
        item.favourite = !item.favourite;
      }
    });
    setVideoData(newArray);
  };

  const handleFilterChange = (type) => {
    setFilterType(type);
  };

  const sourceFiltering = useMemo(() => {
    return filterType
      ? videoData.filter((item) => item.source === filterType)
      : videoData;
  }, [videoData, filterType]);

  const sortDataBy = (sortBy) => {
    if (wasSortedBy) {
      const reversedArr = [...videoData].reverse();
      setVideoData(reversedArr);
    } else {
      const sortedArr = [...videoData].sort((a, b) => b[sortBy] - a[sortBy]);
      setWasSortedBy(true);
      setVideoData(sortedArr);
    }
  };

  const exportToJsonFile = () => {
    let dataStr = JSON.stringify(videoData);
    let dataUri =
      "data:application/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(dataStr);

    let exportFileDefaultName = "videoData.json";

    let linkElement = document.createElement("a");
    linkElement.setAttribute("href", dataUri);
    linkElement.setAttribute("download", exportFileDefaultName);
    linkElement.click();
  };

  const handleJsonImport = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsText(e.target.files[0], "UTF-8");
    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
      const convertedData = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
      setVideoData([...convertedData]);
    };
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("videoData", JSON.stringify(videoData));
  }, [videoData]);

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        inputURL,
        videoData: sourceFiltering,
        handleInputURLChange,
        handleVideoAdd,
        deleteVideo,
        toggleFavourite,
        handleFilterChange,
        videoSources,
        sortDataBy,
        deleteAllData,
        exportToJsonFile,
        handleJsonImport,
        handleVideoModalClose,
        handleVideoModalShow,
        showVideoModal,
        modalData,
        showWrongUrlModal,
        handleWrongUrlModalShow,
        handleWrongUrlModalClose,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}
export { ContextProvider, Context };
```

- App.js (not converted to TS yet)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { ContextProvider } from "./Context.tsx";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ContextProvider>
      <App />
    </ContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you created your context you defaulted it to `undefined`.

This happens here: `const Context = React.createContext(undefined)`

You can't say `undefined.handleVideoAdd`. But you could theoretically say `{}.handleVideoAdd`.

So if you default your context to `{}` at the start like this: `const Context = React.createContext({})`

Your app shouldn't crash up front anymore.

**EDIT:** I see you're using TypeScript, in that case you're going to need to create an interface for your context. Something like this:

```
interface MyContext {
  inputURL?: string,
  videoData?: any,
  handleInputURLChange?: () => void,
  handleVideoAdd?: () => void,
  deleteVideo?: () => void,
  // and all the rest of your keys
}
```

Then when creating your context do this:

```
const Context = React.createContext<MyContext>(undefined);
```

Comment: Ahh yeah I forgot to remove undefined from there (tried many things including null)...
but anyway `const Context = React.createContext({});` does not work either.

Comment: Make sure you use an empty object, because nothing is the same as `undefined`

Comment: Ah right, forgot you were using TypeScript, see my edit.